# Selenium locate submit button

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, form-submit

I am working on a selenium script in Python, where I am on this stage trying to locate a submit button.

#### HTML

```
<div class="submit-buttons">
<button class="submit" type="submit">Filter</button>
</div>
```

I've tried and this has not worked.
So I am out of solutions:

```
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Filter').click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Filter').click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name('submit').click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try xpath solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="submit-buttons"]/button[@class="submit"]')
```

If it is still not identifying, the element might be inside a frame, and you have to switch to that frame before finding the element.

Answer (score 1):

*By link text or by partial link text locators are going to work with links only - `a` elements*. Here you have a button. If you want to use the button text, use the following "by xpath" locator:

```
//button[. = "Filter"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()='Filter']')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type=\"submit\"]")).click();
```

Comment: Could you please explain why and how this solves the OPs problem?