# Selenium - Unable to find elements

Tags: selenium

I am new to the Selenium web application automation testing. i am trying to perform on-click operation on a button. Can anyone help me to take any locator from below html elements:

```
<div class="sapUi2LpbOverflowRight sapSuitePBSprite16">
        <button type="button" id="__xmlview0--overflowRight" data-sap-ui="__xmlview0--overflowRight" aria-describedby="__xmlview0--ariaRightButton" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" class="sapUiBtn sapUiBtnNorm sapUiBtnS sapUiBtnStd" title="Next   " style="display: block;"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium locate submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547370/selenium-locate-submit-button)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the attributes of the `WebElement` seems the `WebElement` have a **Overlay**, so we have to induce **`WebDriverWait`** for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait_me = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait_me.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='sapUiBtn sapUiBtnNorm sapUiBtnS sapUiBtnStd']"))).click();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But that did not work. It throws an error: "no such element: Unable to locate element".

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("__xmlview0--overflowRight")).click();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But that doesn't work, throws an error: "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the button's `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='__xmlview0--overflowRight'])).click();
```

Otherwise, you might want to implement an ExplicitWait if the element's hidden property is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try using Id:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("__xmlview0--overflowRight").click()
```

And if "no such element" error is shown then you can put time.sleep

```
time.sleep(30)
driver.find_element_by_id("__xmlview0--overflowRight").click()
```